# All about Spike

Tags: scrum, agile

What is a Spike?
Does it have story/task within the same?
How to estimate Spike

Need to understand when can we add the same in a sprint and how much time it can maximum be of ?

Comment: It seems like you could find a wealth of information by simply Googling it, i.e. "spike software development".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions that can be answered by Google should be answered by Google.

Comment: I agree with Aziz. While the answers found on google are varied, confusing, and often contradictory, the answer in that post is probably as solid of one as you will find.

Answer (score 1):

According to [extremeprogramming.org](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/spike.html) a spike is a proof of concept: "Create spike solutions to figure out answers to tough technical or design problems".

You create a spike when you are uncertain on how to continue.

Answer (score 0):

When a team finds that they cannot estimate on a story because too much is unknown about it, they often decide to have a spike.

A spike is a time-boxed investigation that has one purpose, to understand enough about a story to enable it to be estimated. The time-box is important, as the team is not attempting to complete the story. They are simply doing some investigation (prototyping, background reading, etc.) so that they understand the story better.

Once the spike is complete the team can then bring the story in to a future sprint and will be confident they can estimate on it.